# Как установить значение по умолчанию для столбца в многотабличном запросе?

Tags: sql

У меня есть три таблицы: **Book(Id)**, **Topic(Id)**, **BookTopic(BookId, TopicId)**.
Есть запрос который для каждого Topic возвращает количество Book в этом Topic:

```
SELECT T.Id, T.TopicName, count(BT.TopicId) AS 'BooksCount' 
FROM Topic T, BookTopic BT
WHERE T.Id = BT.TopicId
GROUP BY T.Id, T.TopicName
```

Но есть проблема: если с топиком не связана ни одна книга то такой топик не возвращается. А я хотел что бы такой топик возвращался со значение BooksCount=0.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого следует воспользоваться `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
  T.Id, T.TopicName,
  count(BT.TopicId) AS 'BooksCount' 
FROM
  Topic T
LEFT JOIN
  BookTopic BT
ON
  T.Id = BT.TopicId
GROUP BY
  T.Id, T.TopicName
```